# Deselect a row of tableview search results

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

I have a table view which list countries and I can select multiple raws. I've the option of select and deselect raws. The problem comes when I add a Search bar, I can`t deselect a raw of the results list because the method "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" is never called when I press a results item.

I searched about this problem but nothing,

Thanks in advance,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        //[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        NSDictionary *country = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.selectedItems addObject: country];

    }
    else
    {
        //[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


        NSDictionary *country = [self.countriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.selectedItems addObject: country];
    }

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        //[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        NSDictionary *country = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.selectedItems removeObject:country];

    }else
    {
        //[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        NSDictionary *country = [self.countriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.selectedItems removeObject:country];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling selectRowAtIndexPath inside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath? The cell should already be selected...

Comment: I had to delete that, its because I was testing @Jacob

Comment: Hmmm that's very interesting. I haven't seen that before...